# Не отображается свойство умного фильтра в битриксе, если не войти в админку

Tags: битрикс, фильтрация

Существует свойство "Бренд" типа "привязка к элементу". Проблема заключается в том, что оно нормально работает и отображается в фильтре, но только если зайти под админом. Если этого не сделать, то отображаться будут все, кроме него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что это была привязка к элементам инфоблока, к которому имели доступ только админы. Во вкладке "Доступ" в настройках инфоблока "Бренды" в пункте "Для всех пользователей" достаточно выбрать "чтение", после чего элементы будут отображаться.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/519140)

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/519140)

Comment: @Vasily почему это не является ответом на вопрос?

Comment: @VAndrJ, почему это не является ответом на вопрос?

Comment: @Grundy , написано тем же участником. Галочки нет. Формулировка о проблеме, но не о том, как именно она была решена. Будь дополнительная фраза из разряда "предоставили доступ тем-то, там-то / другое" - никаких претензий не возникло бы.

Comment: @VAndrJ, был вопрос: почему фильтр работает только если смотрит админ, на него дан ответ: потому что была привязка к элементам, которые доступны только админу. Вроде все логично. Автор вопроса, вполне может дать ответ на свой вопрос, если разобрался с ним сам.

Comment: @Grundy, я же не о том, что автор не может дать ответ на свой вопрос. Оно-то все логично, но решения задачи не видно. Если есть задача показать все свойства, а одно не показывается, так как доступно только админам. Как решена эта задача? Забили и не показываем / еще чего? Или я неправильно понял вопрос и нужно было просто понять почему свойство показывается только админам, поняли и ладно, идем дальше?